# CSS margins acting strange

Tags: css, responsive-design, margin, percentage

So I'm found an article on responsive design [(here)](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design) and I tried to make something like what it had on part of the tutorial. The site said to divid the size of the element by the size of the container that the element(s) are in. (the reason I divided by 1000 and not 1050 is because the margins on the div#main make it 1000px even though the header is 1050px) If that doesn't make sense than the link can explain it. It looks fine with my browser at full size, but if I shrink the window to much then it doesn't resize the way it should. I'm not exactly sure what part of my code is wrong but if someone could help me that would be great! [Here's](http://addisonbean.com/responsive.html) a link to the page I made. And here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}    

header {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    height: inherit;
    max-width: inherit;
    margin: 25px;
}

.box {
    width: 47.5%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 1.25%;
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float: left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div id="main">
        <span class="box">
        </span>
        <span class="box">
        </span>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which browser are you trying ? I tried your sample page from Chrome, it works perfectly fine and couldn't see any problem :(

Comment: I'm using Chrome beta, although I don't think the the beta would matter. Did you try resizing it? It looks fine for me too until it gets a certain size.

Comment: Any specific reason you opted for SPAN ( for class="box") , can you try replacing that too with DIV as anyways you have float:right . I faced a similar problem in the past

Comment: I did that before I added the float:right but I tried replacing the span with divs and it does the same thing. It works fine until the width for the header goes under the max-width.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem in Firefox down to about 200px wide. Please be more specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: Once the header becomes smaller then the max-width the margins for the div.boxs act weird and it gets crushed/smushed. The side margins get too small and it gets pushed up.

Comment: @addison, I tried to click/drag and resize to smallest size possible but still couldn't reproduce your problem :( . It works like a charm. Can you please try with other stable browser versions and let us know what you see ?

Comment: @addison when the viewport is large then the value of margin `1.25%` is large when the viewport get smaller on resizing the value of `1.25%` also get smaller that is why it is acting weirdly.

Comment: I tried it on Safari, Opera, and Firefox and the same thing happened on all them. So is there a different value I should be using for the margin of .box instead of 1.25%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if I explain what's happening you'll see that there actually is no problem.

The inner boxes have a fixed height based on 75% of the parent container's height. Therefore, the heights of all elements stay the same. However, your margins are fractions of the parent element's width, therefore they change with the page width. As the page gets smaller, the margin gets smaller. Since a div naturally lies as high on the page as it can, it moves toward the border of its parent.

All this is expected with your design. To fix it, set fixed top and bottom margins:

```
.box {margin: 12px 1.25%;}
```

Comment: @isherwood I am really interested to know why the top margin given a % unit is changing based on the width, rather than the height here.

Comment: Nevermind. CSS 2 documentation specifies this behaviour. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties